# java.lang.NullPointerException in uployding File Struts

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, struts, struts-1

I´m working with Struts 1.3.10 in Eclipse, I'm developing a web app, I'm using JSP, well, I'm implementing a JSP where I upload a file, but is giving me problems. I have the next code and configurations.

```
<body>
    <html:form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        <input type="file" name="fichier" /> 
      <tr>
          <td><html:submit property="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
          <td align="left"><html:reset/></td>
      </tr>
    </html:form>
</body>
```

In the Form bean I have

```
public class uploadForm extends ActionForm  {
protected FormFile fichier;
public FormFile getFichier() 
   {   
      return fichier;
   }

   public void setFile(FormFile fichier) 
   {
      this.fichier = fichier;}}
```

In the Action I have

```
public class uploadAction extends Action  {
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, 
        HttpServletRequest req, 
        HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {
       
        String resultat = null;
        FormFile fichier = ((uploadForm) form).getFichier();
        String fileName = fichier.getFileName();
        System.out.println(fileName);
        return mapping.findForward(resultat);
    }
}
```

In the struts-config I have

```
<form-beans type="org.apache.struts.action.ActionFormBean">
  <form-bean name="uploadForm" type="struts.ActionForm.uploadForm" />
</form-beans><action-mappings type="org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping">

    <action path="/fiche" input="/FormulaireFiche.jsp" scope="request"
    name="FicheRenseignementForm" type="struts.action.FicheRenseignementAction">
      <forward name="succes" path="/personnel_succes.jsp" redirect="false" />
      <forward name="echec" path="/FormulaireFiche.jsp" redirect="false" />
    </action></action-mappings>
```

And when I run the aplication, and I select the file, the server send me the exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:286)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

cause mère

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
struts.action.uploadAction.execute(uploadAction.java:21)
org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:304)
org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Comment: Please post *full* stack trace (with cause). It should help to identify the problem

Comment: What's on line 21 of uploadAction? And not to be picky (ok, maybe I am...), you're not following standard Java naming conventions. Class names should start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: line 21 of uploadAction : String fileName= fichier.getFileName();

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems here:

1) You need to have a html form binded to your FormFile object (Property) Just like that:

`<html:file property="fichier"/>`

2) Your setter has incorrect name - it won't be able to set the value in your form object. It must be `setFichier(FormFile fichier)`

3) `property="submit"` not needed in `<html:submit />`

Start resolving the bug with these things.

Answer (score 0):

The value of action attribute in `html:form` tag should be equal to what you have used in `action-mapping` tag in `struts-config.xml`. Use either `/upload` or `/fiche` in the action attribute.

You can just use `<html:submit value="Submit"/>`. Since the UploadForm doesnt have the property "submit" you will get error if you include property attribute in `html:submit` tag.

Change the access modifier of `FormFile fichier;` to `public` so that the Action class gets the reference of the form object. and change the method `setFile` to `setFichier`

The value of `resultat` is null. Assign a forward name such as `succes`.

The name and input  attribute values of the action tag should also be changed from `FicheRenseignementForm` to `UploadForm`

Answer (score 0):

Rename `setFile` method to setter `setFichier`. Struts unable to set this field upon submit caused you by NPE.